# GridDB on Oracle Linux

Tags: oracle, linux, griddb

I need to install GridDB on an Oracle Linux 7.9 machine. There are 3 GridDB distributions, for:

1. CentOS 7.9
2. Ubuntu 18.04
3. openSUSE 15.1

I am ruling out Ubuntu as being the farthest from Oracle Linux, but hesitate between CentOS and openSUSE.

I am tending to think CentOS https://linux.oracle.com/switch/centos/

> Is this just another CentOS? Inasmuch as they're both 100%
> binary-compatible with Red Hat Enterprise Linux, yes, this is just
> like CentOS. Your applications will continue to work without any
> modification whatsoever. However, there are several important
> differences that make Oracle Linux far superior to CentOS.

Which distribution is most likely to work on Oracle Linux?
Are there any special requirements for GridDB on Oracle Linux?

Comment: I do not understand the question exactly, Oracle Linux is distro itself.

Comment: Sorry, @paganini, I was not clear. There are 3 GridDB distributions which are designed for 3 different Linux distributions, but not an Oracle Linux specific GridDB distro. I reworded the opening statement so I hope that is clear